# Why is there a random bracket, "]", above the canvas element on my web app?

Tags: javascript, html

[image: Web App with random bracket in the left corner]

Above is an image that contains the random bracket I ram referring to. You can see in the developer tools at the bottom, that the bracket seems to be inserted at the top of the `body` tag. I have been doing a little research, but I cannot figure out why this random bracket is there. My code is below.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>First Game</title>]
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <style type="text/css">
            * 
            {
                padding: 0;
                margin: 0;
            }

            canvas 
            {
                background: #eee;
                display: block;
                margin: 0 auto;
            }
        </style>
</head>
<body>
    <canvas id="myCanvas" width="480" height="320"></canvas>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
        var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.rect(10, 40, 50, 50);
        ctx.fillStyle = "#eee";
        ctx.fill();
        ctx.closePath();
    </script>
</body>
```

As you can see, there is not a stray square bracket in the code. I am not sure why this is appearing. As a side note, this bracket is making the red square, and any other code, to not show up in the canvas. Any ideas?

Comment: wow.....I guess it is one of those days. Thank you.

Comment: Well, it was a good lesson learned.

Answer (score 4):

Your stray square bracket occurs on this line:

```
<title>First Game</title>]
```

The fourth line in your code.

Comment: Thank you. I am cannot believe I missed that and even more that anyone actually even took the time to answer this stupid question. Thank you for pointing out my mistake.

Answer (score 4):

Because you have a rogue `]` character after your `<title>` tag:

```
<title>First Game</title>]
```

Answer (score 2):

In the head where your title tag is you have a ] at the end.

```
<title>Title </title>]
```

When I get stumped on something simple like this, I like to take the dog for a walk, Or play with my kid for a minute then come back. After you clear your mind it's much easier to see something like this.

Comment: Thanks for the tip :). I think I need that.